# Regular Expression to Validate Specific Input While Allowing Empty Input

Tags: regex

I'm trying to validate a textbox containing a variety of acceptable inputs:

- "123456789"
- "123456789+1"
- ""

I'm using this regular expression to validate the first two conditions:

```
^[0-9]{9}\+[0-9]$
```

But now I can't figure out how to allow the user not to enter anything, I've tried things like encapsulating the expression in `()?` , or changing the `{9}` to `{0,9}`, but this allows for a variable number of numbers in the first group (as it MUST be 9, or none)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
^([0-9]{9}\+[0-9])?$
```

The `?` means "0 or 1 copies of the preceding expression." In this case, the entire parenthesized expression is made optional.

Also, if you want the `\+[0-9]` part to be optional, you will likely want to do the same to that; wrap in in parentheses and make it optional with `?`:

```
^([0-9]{9}(\+[0-9])?)?$
```

Comment: This one allows me to have options 2 and 3 from my list, but not option 1

Comment: @Brett My second example should allow you to have option 1 as well. You can test it here: http://rubular.com/r/bxFzEVFMZO

Comment: Wonderful, thanks!! yeah, that makes sense to have the second part in parenthesis too, I've been reading about these and feel like I'm learning a bit, but keep getting hic-cups.. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
^(?:[0-9]{9}\+[0-9])?$
```

Comment: Like Brian, this one allows me to have options 2 and 3 from my list, but not option 1